# Adds permissions to my app make not compatible with a lot of devices

Tags: android, google-play

I add (app update) this permissions to my google play app

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
```

I have six physical devices to test. I test app in 6 devices in device debug mode, then upload app to play store to update app version.

Now my app is updated in play store. I download from play store in this devices. In 3/6 devices now I can´t download app because in play store I get error that device is not compatible. If I run app in this devices manually installing apk app works correctly.

Why I can´t download app in this devices, but app work ok on them?

Samsung galaxy tab 3

Samsung galaxy tab 4

LG-e410

Min. and target don´t change in update:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `android.permission.REC` permission.

Comment: Yes, I only show here updated permissions in update. This are not full permission in manifest. The app in last update record audio, now record audio and video.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I don´t understand you ok in my last response. Then I delete this permission and see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely happening because of this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
```

That will restrict your app to only get installed on devices which declare that they have a front facing camera.  The LGE LG-E410 only has a single, rear facing camera.

If you do not absolutely require a front-facing camera, you should remove this.  If you are using the old `Camera` class, you can pull `CameraInfo` and check if the specific camera instance is front or rear facing.  If using the newer camera2 API, you can enumerate the cameras using `CameraManager` and get the `CameraCharacteristics` for each and that will tell you if they are front or rear facing.

Comment: Samsung galaxy tab 3 and Samsung galaxy tab 4 have front + rear camera. Anyway I will remove this permission and tell if that was the problem.

Comment: It could be another feature you have declared, such as the auto focus. The point is that if you declare that the app uses a feature, by default it will treat is as required. If it is optional, then include the `android:required="false"` attribute in the `<uses-feature>` tag. See here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html